# RequireJS and Making validate method available in js file

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have the following config.js

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/static/js",
  paths: {
    jquery: "src/jquery-1.7.2",
    jqueryui: "src/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/js/jquery-ui-custom", 
    angular: "src/angular/1.0.4/angular",
    bootstrap: "bootstrap/js/bootstrap"
  },
  shim: {
    "jquery-validation-1.10.0/dist/jquery.validation.min" : {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "jquery.validation"
    }
  }
});
```

In a js file that I am loading up (named `signup.js`), I am attempting to make the `validate` method from jquery validation plugin available.

```
# File signup.js

define(["jquery"], function($) {

$('#beta_signup_form button[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");

$('#beta_signup_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true 
        }
    },
    focusCleanup: true,
    onkeyup: false,
    errorElement: "span",
      ... the rest of the code ...
```

I am getting an error in my console which says `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'`.

How do I pass in the `validate` method to my `signup.js` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to tweak your config a little. Typically when shimming a module you need to give it a path as well:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/static/js",
  paths: {
    jquery: "src/jquery-1.7.2",
    jqueryui: "src/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/js/jquery-ui-custom", 
    angular: "src/angular/1.0.4/angular",
    bootstrap: "bootstrap/js/bootstrap",
    // Give validate a path
    "jquery-validate": "jquery-validation-1.10.0/dist/jquery.validation.min" 
  },
  shim: {
    // Now shim it
    "jquery-validate": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "jquery.validation"
    }
  }
});


// Define it as a dependency. If the plugin doesn't return a value
// (most just augment the jQuery.fn) then no need to pass an argument 
// to your callback.    
define(["jquery", "jquery-validate"], function($) {
    // module code
});
```

You can shorten the code further if the plugin doesn't export a value:

```
  shim: {
    "jquery-validate": ["jquery"]
  }
```

More examples in the official docs - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: This seems to load up jquery.validate.js but now, jquery.validate.js itself gives me an error saying that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`. Any idea why this would be so?

Comment: I've found the shim to be patchy at best in the past, depending on how the plugin is written. I settled for wrapping it with a define myself. Not ideal I admit but works reliably.

Comment: I just spent some time trying to get this solution to work but got stuck. After reading these comments I'm a bit confused... So this answer doesn't actually work? I have to essentially fork the plugin and wrap it in define? If this is the case, you ought to edit the answer with that info.

Comment: ah, I think I was able to solve my issues by just removing the `exports` property in the config. Once the code loads its added to the global jQuery object which is available via require-jquery.js by default so I think its unnessecary.